# vuex, getters should be function but "getters.allTodos" in module "todos" is []

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex

I'm getting `[vuex] getters should be function but "getters.allTodos" in module "todos" is [].` error and I don't know why. I was looking into docs and it seems that I should assign a object with functions to `getters` like I'm doing this in code below. But it doesn't work.

```
import { createStore } from "vuex";
import Task from "@/classes/Task";
const store = createStore({
    state: {
        todos: [] as Task[],
    },
    mutations: {
        addTask(state, payload: Task) {
            state.todos.push(payload);
        },
    },
    actions: {
        addTask({ commit }, task: Task) {
            commit("addTask", task);
        },
    },
    getters: { allTodos: (state) => state.todos },
});
export default store;
```

Comment: You are likely importing it wrong. Are you using `createStore` again at import side?

Comment: Absolutely nothing wrong with the code shown.  [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76783601/edit) the question and include code showing how the store/getter is being used.